# Как вывести данные из бд MS SQL в datagrid wpf C#?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Как не пытался вывести но никак не получается вывести.
В коде xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg_collection" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

и код для вывода:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Db_connection.String_Connection());
   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select theme from themes", connection))
   {
      connection.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      adapter.Fill(dt);
      dg_collection.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
      connection.Close();
   }
```

После этого кода должно было вывести строки из таблицы, но этого не происходит, не могу понять почему. Второй день в поисках:)

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/walkthrough-display-data-from-a-sql-server-database-in-a-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: а если вывод производится из ms sql server 2014, каким образом тогда?

Comment: разницы не будет